# Effect on shortest paths after edges have been deleted

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

An input of directed graph has been provided and I have found shortest paths to a particular node 'T' using both - asynchronous and synchronous Bellman-Ford algorithm.
I was trying to find out the effect on the shortest paths after some edges are deleted. 
In my approach, I tried to mark the distances at start nodes of the deleted edges as infinity and was trying to apply asynchronous Bellman-Ford, but I get stuck at the point because other nodes will not update their value as they already have the shortest path minimum value.

Can anyone help me to figure out a way to find the new shortest paths without having to run the full algorithm again on the new graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. And a simple explanation can be found in Bellman-Ford algorithm itself:

If V is the set of nodes. A minimal path from starting node to any other node will pass maximum |V| nodes ( |V|-1 edges). This is the reason why you relax the edges for |V|-1 time, so that the 'information' from all nodes will propagate to the source.

Is you already have applied Bellman-Ford algorithm on a graph, you can start relaxing all the deleted node's neighbors and propagate the changes to their neighbors until a path that wasn't using the deleted node (until no updates are being made). Aware of negative cycle.